# Como escribir esta clase

Tags: python, clase

Se me pidió escribir una clase que creara objetos, esta clase tenia que tomar la información de algunos elementos y usar ciertos métodos para ver si es True o False.

```
import numpy as np

# Escriba la clase aca

#Declaracion de datos
data = []
data.append(["J Araneda", 1.0, 3.0, 7.0])
data.append(["K Bahamondes", 4.0, 4.0, 4.0])
data.append(["J Carrasco", 3.0, 3.0, 3.0])
data.append(["H Diaz", 3.0, 4.0, 5.0])
data.append(["I Elgueta", 6.0, 4.0, 3.5])
data.append(["J Faundez", 5.0, 4.5, 6.5])
data.append(["G Gutierrez", 4.0, 5.0, 5.5])
data.append(["F Hernandez", 5.0, 4.6, 4.5])
data.append(["H Isla", 6.0, 6.0, 6.0])
data.append(["A Jodorowsky", 7.0, 4.7, 6.1])

############################
A = []
for i in data:
    tmp = Alumno(i)
    A.append(tmp)

print(Igual_Promedio(A[0], A[8]))
print(Promedio(A[4]))
print(Igual_Nota(1, A[7], A[8])) #1 es la primera evaluación
print(Muestra_Notas(A[4]))
print(Muestra_Nombre(A[2]))
```

intenté varias veces crear el código, pero no se como tomar la información de los datos y ponerla dentro de mi clase para que haga los métodos.
Gracias

Comment: Puedes añadir el código donde defines la clase `Alumno`?

Comment: el coldigo es class `class Alumno:
    def __init__(self, alumnos):
        self.data = []`  se supone que deberia tomar los objetos de la lista `data` pero no entiendo como hago que los tome PS: disculpa que el codigo salga horizontal, nose como ponerlo ordenado aqui

Comment: me di cuenta que la lista de los alumnos la deberia tomar de la lista que se va creando de data, pero aun no se bien como hacer que la tome, puesto que pongo este codigo `class Alumno:
    Alumno = data` pero me dice que el nombre `data` no esta definido, ¿como deberia definirlo para que lo tome?

Comment: Primero, debes de adjuntar ese código en tu pregunta (**editandola**), con el botón que dice editar debajo de la pregunta. Por lo que entiendo ocupas saber: ¿Cómo usar una variable de tu código como atributo de tu clase¨?

Comment: Si, exactamente eso, disculpa si es dificil entenderme, soy bastante nuevo en esto de programar, mis principal problema es que el codigo me dice que no defino el nombre `Alumno`, y no estoy seguro de como hacer una clase que tome la lista de `data`

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta, la acabo de publicar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me gustaría primero explicarte como es todo esto de las clases y objetos, de los atributos y métodos. Siempre es bueno tener la [referencia de la documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) a mano.

Un clase funciona como "plantilla" para generar diferentes objetos. Lo que tienen en común los objetos generados por una misma clase, es el hecho de que tiene los mismo atributos y métodos.

Lo bueno de que una clase funcione como plantilla es que se puede generar objetos con diferentes valores para cada atributo, y obtener diferentes resultados de los mismos métodos. El uso de clases tiene el fin de reutilizar variables (atributos) y funciones (métodos).

**¿Cómo se define una clase?**

Por convención las clases se inicializan con el método `__init__()`:

```
class Persona():
    def __init__(self):
        #Atributos
```

Pero esto no quiere decir que no hayan otras manera de inicializar clases, por lo mismo te recomiendo leer del tema. Sobre todo leer la documentación (adjunta al principio de la respuesta).

**¿Cómo funciona `__init__()`?**

Este método puede recibir cualquier cantidad de argumentos, estos argumentos se van a instanciar como atributos **justo cuando se inicializa la clase (creando un objeto)**. Un ejemplo:

```
class Persona():
    def __init__(self,nombre,edad):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.edad = edad
```

En este fragmento de código se están definiendo dos argumentos, aparte de `self` (después hablaré de `self`), `nombre` y `edad`. A estos se les aplica la misma sentencia, se instancian como atributos:

```
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.edad = edad
```

La palabra `self` quiere decir que se está refiriendo a la misma clase (por eso se llama "self"). Entonces esta sentencia en lenguaje humano se traduciría así:

> El atributo "nombre" de **esta** clase es igual al argumento "nombre" que se use al inicializar la clase.

**Creando un objeto:**

Como digo `__init__()` se ejecuta apenas se crea un objeto, es decir los parámetros que se uitilizron para crear el objeto son los parámetros de `__init__()`. Veamos un ejemplo de como se crearía un objeto:

```
Juan = Persona("Juan",23)
```

Juan es una persona de 23 años llamada Juan. Eso es todo, ya creamos un objeto!

Si queremos acceder a un atributo de dicho objeto, podemos usar el operador `.`:

```
print(Juan.nombre)
print(Juan.edad)
```

imprimiría

```
Juan
23
```

**¿Que son los métodos?**

Ahora hablemos de métodos, los métodos son funciones definidas dentro de una clase. Se pueden acceder a estos de la misma manera que con los atributos (con el operador `.`). Estos tienen acceso a los atributos de la clase de **manera nativa**, es decir se pueden definir con los atributos.

Intentemos definir un método:

```
class Persona():
    def __init__(self,nombre,edad):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.edad = edad

    def presentacion(self):
        print(f"Hola me llamo {self.nombre}, y tengo {self.edad} años de edad")
```

Nuestra clase ya va tomando forma, se usa el argumento `self` para definir que es un método de la propia clase, y como dije antes se pueden usar los atributos.

```
Juan = Persona("Juan",23)
Juan.presentacion()
```

muestra:

```
Hola me llamo Juan, y tengo 23 años de edad
```

Además te recuerdo que las clases sirven como plantillas, puedes generar más objetos con atributos diferentes:

```
Jimena = Persona("Jimena",19)
Jimena.presentacion()
```

muestra:

```
Hola me llamo Jimena, y tengo 19 años de edad
```

Se pueden definir cuantos métodos y atributos se quieran. Hay mucho más que ver con este tema, como los métodos mágicos y otras formas de instanciar atributos, pero eso te lo voy a dejar a ti (para que lo investigues).

**Por qué tu código está mal?**

Es lo mismo que acabo de explicar, no estás creando objetos e instanciando los atributos de la manera adecuada. Una solución:

```
alumnos = []
for i in data:
    alumnos.append(Alumno(i))
```

Esto claro con antes haber definido la clase `Alumno`:

```
class Alumno():
    def __init__(self,datos):
        self.datos = datos
```

Esto hará que `self.datos` sea la lista que se paso como argumento al inicializar la clase- Osea `i` en el ciclo `for`.

**Nota:** No es lo más conveniente añadir los elementos a `data` linea, por linea. Deberías de leer sobre el método [`extend()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). También sería bueno almacenar los objetos en variables, para tener más control. Solo faltaría que definieras los métodos que te pidieron, eso ya sabes hacerlo ;).

Espero te haya servido!

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por darte el tiempo de explicar, ahora si pude hacer bien el problema.

Answer (score 1):

Con cada elemento de tu lista `data` vamos a crear un nuevo objeto de tipo `Alumno`.

Primero creamos la clase Alumno asi

```
class Alumno:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
```

Ahora vamos a crear los objetos utilizando la lista data

```
for d in data:
    Alumno(d)
```

Esto se ve bien pero tenemos todavia un problema, estamos perdiendo la referencia a los objetos creados y asi no vamos a poder utilizarlos.

Para esto por ej podemos crear una lista de alumnos donde vamos a guardar cada instancia

```
listaAlumnos = []
for d in data:
    listaAlumnos.append(Alumno(d))
```

Ahora podemos ver los datos de los alumnos que creamos usando

```
listaAlumnos[index].data
```

Ahora ya sabiendo esto podemos continuar con la clase Alumno y agregarle los metodos que necesitas

```
class Alumno:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def MuestraNotas(self):
        print(self.data[1:])

    def MuestraNombre(self):
        print(self.data[0])
        
    def IgualPromedio(self, otro):
        # Aca continua, recuerda que self hace referencia al objeto que esta llamando
        # Si tenes 2 objetos llamados alumno1 y alumno2
        # haces alumno1.IgualPromedio(alumno2)
        # alumno1 = self, alumno2 = otro
        pass
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!, entendi bastante bien la explicacion, te lo agradezco.